# wgcna goodSamplesGenes error about too few genes

Tags: r

I have three treatments 1, 2 and 3. There are three replicates for each treatment so I averaged all replicates for each treatment. There are 30,000 genes in total. I have 10 phenotypes for these three treatments as well. I am trying to use WGCNA to identify genes that are critical among these three treatments. I am using:

```
library(WGCNA)
allowWGCNAThreads() 
##Gene Expression
library(readr)
Expression_File <- read.csv("gene_expression.csv")
Expression_File <- select(Expression_File, Gene_ID, A1, B1, C1)
Expression_File[Expression_File == 0] <- NA
dim(Expression_File)
names(Expression_File)
GE.adjusted=Expression_File
rownames(GE.adjusted)=GE.adjusted[,1]
GE.adjusted=GE.adjusted[,-1]
GE.adjusted=t(GE.adjusted)

##Phenotype
Phenotype_File <- read.csv("phenotype.csv")
dim(Phenotype_File)
Phenotype_File[Phenotype_File == 0] <- NA
Phenotype <- Phenotype_File 
a=Phenotype[,1]
Phenotype=Phenotype[,-1]
Phenotype=t(Phenotype)
Phenotype=as.matrix(Phenotype,ncol=10)
colnames(Phenotype)=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10")

##Checking data for excessive missing values and identification of outlier samples
gsg = goodSamplesGenes(GE.adjusted, verbose = 3)
gsg$allOK
```

But I got an error:

```
Flagging genes and samples with too many missing values...
  ..step 1
Error in goodGenes(GE.adjusted, weights, goodSamples, goodGenes, minFraction = minFraction,  : 
  Too few genes with valid expression levels in the required number of samples.
```

I will appreciate any suggestion to fix this error. Thank you!

Comment: I think you're more likely to find an answer for this bioinformatics-focused question at bioconductor (https://support.bioconductor.org/) - the author of the WGCNA package frequently answers questions there.